# Should I synchronize before unbinding a texture in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, textures, gpu

I'm using a texture memory for one of my kernel programs.

I bind the texture memory, than call the kernel execution that uses the texture memory, and finally I unbind the texture. I'm trying to figure out if there is any possibility that my device  would unbind texture before my kernel execution end? Or either way, would unbind command would failed ?

```
     cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>();
     cudaBindTexture(NULL,tex,d_buffer,desc,iw,ih,d_bufferStride));

     KernelTextureCall<<<100,100,0,streamObject>>>();
     cudaGetLastError(); 

     // Should I sych or not ? 
     cudaUnbindTexture(tex);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to synchronize before `cudaUnbindTexture`. It contains implicit synchronization.

Comment: Can you please find the source for that? I was looking everywhere inside the cuda programming guide, couldn't find anything related